# InvalidArgumentError: In[0].dim(0) and In[1].dim(0) must be the same: [1,125,150] vs [32,150,125]

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras, keras-layer

I'm trying to create a custom layer merging 2 sources.  I am receiving the error "InvalidArgumentError: In[0].dim(0) and In[1].dim(0) must be the same: [1,125,150] vs [32,150,125]." The code runs if I set the batch_size to 1 so then have [1,125,150] vs [1,150,125]; however, the loss then doesn't change so still not root cause. I think that I need to use batch size instead of just expand dims

```
class mergeLayer(L.Layer):
    def __init__(self, output_dim, **kwargs):
        self.output_dim = output_dim
        super(mergeLayer,self).__init__()
        self.kernel_initializer = INIT.get('uniform')

    def build(self, input_shape):
        # Create a trainable weight variable for this layer.
        self.kernel = self.add_weight(name='kernel',shape=input_shape[1:],initializer=self.kernel_initializer,trainable=True)
        super(mergeLayer,self).build(input_shape) # Be sure to call this somewhere!

    def call(self, x):
        temp = K.batch_dot(tf.expand_dims(self.kernel,0),tf.transpose(x,perm=[0,2,1]))+1
        return temp
    def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
        return input_shape
```

Below is code fitting the model. Again, if I change batch_size to 1 here, I can the code to run but loss stays the same.

```
modelMerge.fit(x=[train1,train2],y=cats,epochs=100,batch_size=32,shuffle='batch')
score = modelMerge.evaluate(x=[test1,test2],y=cats,batch_size=32)
```

Output when batch_size is 1

```
Epoch 1/100
3903/3903 [=========================] - 45s - loss: 15.7062 - acc: 0.0254
Epoch 2/100
3903/3903 [=========================] - 43s - loss: 15.7050 - acc: 0.0254
Epoch 3/100
277/3903 [=>.......................] - ETA: 42s - loss: 15.8272 - acc: 0.0181
```

Thanks very much for your time and help.

Updated: here is the Keras model structure that calls mergeLayer

```
def buildModel_merge(numClasses):
source = L.Input(shape=(64,25,1))
x = L.Conv2D(150, (3,3), activation='relu', name='conv1a')(source)
x = L.MaxPooling2D((2,2))(x)
x = L.BatchNormalization()(x)
x = L.Conv2D(150, (3,3), activation='relu', name='conv2a')(x)
x = L.Conv2D(150, (5,5), activation='relu', name='conv3a')(x)
x = L.Dropout(0.5)(x)
#reshape into a dxN matrix
x = L.Reshape((125,150))(x)
x = mergeLayer(100)(x)

source2 = L.Input(shape=(30,30,30,1))
x2 = L.Conv3D(32,(5,5,5),strides=(2,2,2),activation='relu',name='conv1b')(source2)
x2 = L.Dropout(0.2)(x2)
x2 = L.Conv3D(32,(3,3,3),activation='relu',name='conv2b')(x2)
x2 = L.MaxPooling3D(pool_size=(2,2,2),name='pool2b')(x2)
x2 = L.Dropout(0.3)(x2)
#reshape into a dxM matrix
x2 = L.Reshape((125,32))(x2)
x2 = mergeLayer(100)(x2)

#x = L.Multiply(x, x2)(x)
x = L.Multiply()([x,x2])

x = L.Flatten()(x)
x = L.Dense(400, activation='relu', name='dense1')(x) # Is relu used here?
x = L.Dropout(0.5)(x)
classify = L.Dense(numClasses, activation='softmax', name='dense2')(x)

model = M.Model(inputs=[source,source2],outputs=classify)
optimizer= O.SGD(momentum=0.02)
model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['acc'])

return model
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some corrections in your code:

- You don't need the `output_dim` and the `**kwargs` arguments
- Instead of using `expand_dims` on the kernel, I already defined it with the extra dimension (but your keras version seem to behave different from mine, so use the `#alternative` lines of code).
- **Main problem**: the `batch_dot` is expecting two tensors with the same batch size (that means: the first dimension must be the same)

  - Solved it by repeating the kernel to fit the batch size of `x`
- Exchanged all `tf` functions with keras backend functions (`import keras.backend as K`) - This is not a problem, but you may port this solution to other supported backends with this.

.

```
class mergeLayer(Layer):

    #your init doesn't need output_dim and **kwargs
    def __init__(self):
        super(mergeLayer,self).__init__()
        self.kernel_initializer = INIT.get('uniform')

    def build(self, input_shape):
        # Create a trainable weight variable for this layer.
        self.kernel = self.add_weight(
                          name='kernel',

                          #corrected shape to avoid expand_dims
                          shape=(1,)+input_shape[1:],
                              #alternative:
                              #shape = input_shape[1:],
                          initializer=self.kernel_initializer,trainable=True)

        super(mergeLayer,self).build(input_shape) # Be sure to call this somewhere!

    def call(self, x):
        #take a tensor of ones with the same shape as x
        form = K.ones_like(x)

        #multiplies the kernel to match the batch size of x
        kernel = form * self.kernel
            #alternative:
            #kernel = form * K.expand_dims(self.kernel,0)

        #used K.permute_dimensions instead of tf
        temp = K.batch_dot(kernel,K.permute_dimensions(x,(0,2,1)))+1
        return temp

    def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
        return input_shape
```

Comment: Thank you. I’m now getting error TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given) at call x = mergeLayer(100)(x)

Comment: If I update init to accept two arguments, then get this error: self.kernel = self.add_weight(name='kernel',shape=(1,)+input_shape[1:],initializer=self.kernel_initializer,trainable=True)
TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "TensorShape") to tuple

Comment: Added Keras model structure that calls mergeLayer. Thanks so much for your help

Comment: So, you don't need that "100" when calling the layer. Call just `mergeLayer()(x)`

Comment: The other error is strange... I don't have it (I tested). Maybe it's about the keras version you're using. But that can be solved by what you were doing before my answer, use `shape=input_shape[1:]` without the (1,). And add the `expand_dims` before multiplying the kernel in `call`.

Comment: In the kernel definition: `shape=input_shape[1:]` and in the call method `kernel = form * K.expand_dims(self.kernel,0)`

Comment: See the `#alternative` comments in my answer.

Comment: Running but getting output like: Limit:              170852352
InUse:                   108003328
MaxInUse:                108003328
NumAllocs:                      87
MaxAllocSize:             67108864

2018-01-29 13:56:48.864757: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:277]*x**
2018-01-29 13:56:48.864786: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1192] Resource exhausted: OOM when allocating tensor with shape[32]
2018-01-29 13:56:48.868277: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:924] failed to allocate 59.94M (62849024 bytes) from device: CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY

Comment: ResourceExhaustedError (see above for traceback): OOM when allocating tensor with shape[13500,800]
         [[Node: dense1_1/kernel/Initializer/random_uniform/RandomUniform = RandomUniform[T=DT_INT32, _class=["loc:@dense1_1/kernel"], dtype=DT_FLOAT, seed=0, seed2=0, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0"](dense1_1/kernel/Initializer/random_uniform/shape)]]

Comment: It's running on a shared GPU server and someone else is running a high memory application now so I'll try again later and should work. Thanks very very much!!!

Comment: Ok... that error is indeed memory shortage. It's not related to this question.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. You’ve answered the question but could you help me figure out why loss is not decreasing based on the code? I ran with 100 epochs and 32 batch size and getting same loss each epoch. Thanks again

Comment: Exactly the same without any change at all even at the small decimals? Sometimes I get so small differences that they don't appear in the numbers shown, this might be a too small learning rate. You could try increasing the learning rate of your SGD -- Usually I prefer going with `optimizer='adam'`, it's more autoadapting to the needs.